In which scriptures it is written that one who is constantly engaged in devotion of Krishna is free from all debts?
In which scriptures it is written that one who is constantly engaged in devotion of Krishna is free from all debts (Pitri Rina, Deva Rina , Rishi Rina etc).
Is it mentioned in any other scriptures other then one linked in this question.
Also it needn't be about devotion to Krishna only but any other god.

The verse being referred to by Premanandji Maharaj is likely the following from the Ekadash Skand (11th Canto of Shrimad Bhagavatam):

देवर्षिभूताप्तनृणां पितृणां
न किङ्करो नायमृणी च राजन् ।
सर्वात्मना य: शरणं शरण्यं
गतो मुकुन्दं परिहृत्य कर्तम् ॥ ४१ ॥


O King, one who has given up all material duties and has taken full
shelter of the lotus feet of Mukunda, who offers shelter to all, is
not indebted to the demigods, great sages, ordinary living beings,
relatives, friends, mankind or even one’s forefathers who have passed
away. Since all such classes of living entities are part and parcel of
the Supreme Lord, one who has surrendered to the Lord’s service has no
need to serve such persons separately.

